# Is there any good literature about conceptual designs of Quantum (Micro-) Black Holes Machines?

Tags: soft-question, black-holes

I did some research and found this book:

Quantum Black Holes, 2014
http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-38939-9

It seems good for a repetition of current status of (Quantum) Black Hole theory. However, from just looking at table of contents, it does not seem to cover the topic of possible Quantum Black Holes Machines. Does anyone know better sources for conceptual designs, size etc. for these maybe possible machines?